# How to prevent the screensaver occasionally showing "No photos"?

Tags: screensaver

I have my screensaver set to show photos from a shared album in my photo library. Normally this works fine, but occasionally it fails to load any of the photos and just shows a black screen with the message "No photos".

I haven't been able to figure out any pattern to when it works and when it doesn't, except that manually forcing the screensaver by pushing the mouse pointer into the designated "Hot Corner" always works.

This is a MacBook Pro running Mojave 10.14.5, but this issue has been happening for ages: it wasn't introduced by any of the Mojave point releases, for sure.

Comment: This also seems to be an issue in Big Sur as it just recently started happening after the upgrade to 11.2

Comment: Also an issue with MacBook Pro, Apple M1 Max chip, macOS Ventura Version 13.3. My folder with jpg files is on the desktop. When an **external LCD screen** is connected, it will often have a black screen with "No Photos" message, instead of the screensaver. At the very same time, the **laptop** screen shows the jpg files in the screensaver just fine.